# Getting instance of @Autowired annotation field as NULL in controller.

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on creating several RestAPI endpoints for my application. However, I am facing a bit weird isue in one of my controller.

Below is the code I am using,

```
import com.eprocure.webapi.data.dto.OtpDto;
import ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Validated
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/otp")
public class OtpController {

    @Autowired
    private MapperFactory  mapperFactory;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/send", "/resend"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    private ResponseEntity<OtpDto> sendOtp(@Valid @RequestBody OtpDto otpDto) {
        /*
        Using instance of @MapperFactory but
        getting mapperFactory NULL.
         */
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

While executing above code, I am getting my mapperFactory always NULL.

Note: If I remove the @Validated tag from above controller, it works quite fine somehow. I do not know what can be the reason might be.

However, I want to use @Validated annotation in one of the method.

I researched over SO but nothing help me as of now.

Can anybody let me know what can be the issue I am encountering?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to move `mapperFactory` to constructor? It should fail somewhere and it may help to find the root of the problem

Comment: Why would you need `@Validated` on the controller?

Comment: Looks like `@Validated` on class level has a problem with your sendOtp method which is private. I would say, delete `@Validated` on class level or leave it and set the access to public

Comment: The `@Validated` leads to a proxy being created as a `private` method can only access instance variables it will try to locate the `MapperFactory` on the proxy (which will always be `null`) instead of the actual Spring managed instance. Your method should be `public` anyway and not sure why you would need the `@Validated` on the controller anyway.